# No puedo remover el objeto de mi lista DataTable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, hibernate

Estoy dentro de mi service y aca es donde pongo el parametro para que reciba el id de la fila que deseo eliminar .

```
@Transactional
public void eliminaHerramienta(Integer idherramienta) {
    try {
        Herramienta p = manager.find(Herramienta.class, idherramienta);
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.remove(p);
        manager.flush();
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

luego me encuentro en el controlador  para hacer la interaccion con la vista el cual esta como un requestScoped

```
@Transactional
public void eliminar(Integer idherramienta) {
    System.out.println("entrando a eliminar alumno");
    herramientaService.eliminaHerramienta(idherramienta);

}
```

al parecer todo va genial pero no entra al metodo de eliminar al momento cuando le doy click a al boton para llamar esa accion en el controlador.

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{herramientaAction.lstherramienta}" var="h"
        border="1" paginator="true" rows="5">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Id</f:facet>
                        #{h.idherramienta}
                    </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Nombre</f:facet>
                        #{h.name}
                    </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">stock</f:facet>
                        #{h.stock}
                    </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">precio</f:facet>
                        #{h.precio}
                    </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">fecha vencimiento</f:facet>
                        #{h.fecha}
                    </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">modelo</f:facet>
                        #{h.modelo.descripcion}
                    </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton id="btn1"
                action="#{herramientaAction.eliminar(h.idherramienta)}"   value="eliminar" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

como podra ver tiene la vista de un datatable , no se que cosa tengo que agregar para que funcione o reciba esa accion .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema puede ser por varias causas:

1- Asegúrate que tu datatable está dentro de un `<h:form>` ya que esto es obligatorio.

2- Vamos a cambiar en el commandbutton el "action" por "actionlistener". El action es más recomendado cuando existe navegabilidad, es decir si vas a cambiar de una vista a otra o navegar a otro sitio y no es tu caso. Ya que te va a interesar hacer un update de la tabla en la vista cuando se realice la acción de eliminar.

3- Para intentar forzar el asunto añade `process="@this"`, de esta manera le indicamos a JSF que tiene que forzar el envio de la información al servidor. Si sigue sin funcionar cambia por @form.

Nota: Antes de hacer estos pasos ponte un punto de ruptura en el método de eliminar para asegurarnos cuando llegue tu petición.

Comentame si se soluciona con lo anterior.

Un saludo.